# what would setting VSCode exclude affect my development?

Tags: visual-studio-code

VSCode is asking if I want to exclude setting file.

What would setting VSCode exclude affect my development?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What would setting VSCode exclude affect my development?

This only affects whether files and folders that begin with a `.` will be shown in the "Explorer" sidebar of the VSCode GUI. Those files will still exist on your hard drive and your compilers or other tools will still be able  use those files.

This is simply a personal *preference*, some developers want to hide those kinds of files because they can clutter the workspace.

---

If you select **Exclude Globally**, this tells VSCode to hide files that begin with `.` for all of your workspaces. (An application-wide setting)

If you select **Exclude in workspace**, this tells VSCode to hide files that begin with `.` in just that workspace you have open now. (A workspace setting)

If you select **Never**, files that begin with `.` will be visible in the "Explorer" sidebar.